# How could I remove local unexisting branches

Tags: git

These branches not existing on remote origin server anymore,

However I couldn't delete then by

`gb -D origin/feature/support-auto-backup`
or
`gb -D   remotes/origin/feature/add-discussion`

I got this kind of exception `error: branch 'origin/feature/support-auto-backup' not found.`

How could I remove all of them?

## branches on my local working space

```
  remotes/origin/feature/add-discussion
  remotes/origin/feature/add-ios-push-notification
  remotes/origin/feature/add-monitor-and-upstart-service
  remotes/origin/feature/add-ng-highcharts
  remotes/origin/feature/add-paypal-support
  remotes/origin/feature/move-status-watch-to-admin
  remotes/origin/feature/periodic_prices_rake_task
  remotes/origin/feature/personal-watch-list
  remotes/origin/feature/refactor_to_new_model
  remotes/origin/feature/structure_refactor
  remotes/origin/feature/support-auto-backup
  remotes/origin/feature/support-currency-conversion
  remotes/origin/feature/support_add_other_emails
```

Comment: What does `gb` command do, is it some alias?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git fetch --prune` or `git fetch -p` for short. This will fetch an updated list of branches from the remote and update the set of your remote branches to reflect that. If you have remote branches that no longer exist, then those will be removed.

[The manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) explains this option:

> **`-p`
> `--prune`**
>
> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a `--tags` option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit `refspec` (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the `--mirror` option), then they are also subject to pruning.

---

If you want to manually remove remote branches from your local repository, then you cannot just use `git branch -d` or `git branch -D`. By default, it only gives you access to your local branches but not remote branches. However, you can use the `--remote` or `-r` option to delete the branches. Note that you only specify the remote branch name then, without the leading `remotes/`, for example:

```
git branch -d -r origin/feature/add-discussion
```

This functionality is also explained in the manual for [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> Use `-r` together with `-d` to delete remote-tracking branches. Note, that it only makes sense to delete remote-tracking branches if they no longer exist in the remote repository or if git fetch was configured not to fetch them again. See also the prune subcommand of [git-remote[1]](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for a way to clean up all obsolete remote-tracking branches.